# How to count the number of items in the arraylist

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to count the number of items in an arraylist to display it in a chart using chart.js

This is how I am doing it currently, but I am unable to get a count of it.

```js
const dataArray = [];
let labelsArray = ['1 - Very Jialat', '2 - Jialat', '3 - Normal lor', '4 - Shiok a bit', '5 - Shiok ah '];
db.collection('Feedback Ratings').get().then((snapshot => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    FeebackRatings = doc.data().response;

    let response = FeebackRatings.response;
    dataArray.push(FeebackRatings);

    // loop through the data array
    dataArray.forEach(response => {
      // -1 because if value is 1, i want to refer to index 0 of the array
      if (dataArray[response - 1]) {
        dataArray[response - 1] = dataArray[response - 1] += 1
      }
      if (!dataArray[response - 1]) {
        dataArray[response - 1] = 1
      }
    })
  })
}));

// expected outcome = [2, 1, 1] --- where first item in index represents the count of the item
console.log(dataArray);

let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let BarChart = new Chart(myChart, {
  type: 'pie', //can create diff types using this; bar, horizontal, pie, line, donut, radar
  data: {
    labels: labelsArray,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Total number',
      data: dataArray,
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Feedback Statistics',
      fontSize: 25
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: ¿ array.length ?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a JS array, just use

```
dataArray.length
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `.then()`, So I guess you might be dealing with a promise.
If you are dealing with a promise, code after the promise will execute before the code present in .then() will execute. So might need to do this.

1) Convert the code which you need to execute into a function

```
function displayChart(dataArray){
console.log(dataArray);

let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let BarChart = new Chart(myChart, {
  type: 'pie', //can create diff types using this; bar, horizontal, pie, line, donut, radar
  data: {
    labels: labelsArray,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Total number',
      data: dataArray,
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Feedback Statistics',
      fontSize: 25
        }
      }
    });

}
```

2) And call this function at then end of your then () method.

```
const dataArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let labelsArray = ['1 - Very Jialat', '2 - Jialat', '3 - Normal lor', '4 - Shiok a bit', '5 - Shiok ah '];
db.collection('Feedback Ratings').get().then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        FeebackRatings = doc.data().response;

        let response = FeebackRatings.response;


        // loop through the data array
        response.forEach(response, => {
            labelsArray.forEach((value, index) => {
                if (value == response) {
                    dataArray[index]++;
                }

            });

        })
    })
    displayChart(dataArray);
});
```

Comment: I want to match the data in the array to the labels in the form of how many number of '1 - Jialat' there are in the array
Do i use a forloop to count?

Comment: Are you getting the data now ? ..yes you can use for loop to do so..

Comment: Yes. I've got the data from the codes I posted. But I am unsure as to how to do the loop to do a count of the items in the array
the array contains the information like this 
0: "3 - Normal lor"
1: "2 - Jialat"
2: "2 - Jialat"
3: "1 - Very jialat"
4: "1 - Very jialat"
5: "5 - Shiok ah"
6: "2 - Jialat"
7: "1 - Very jialat"
8: "2 - Jialat"
9: "1 - Very jialat"
10: "1 - Very Jialat"
11: "1 - Very jialat"
12: "1 - Very jialat"

Comment: I have the uncaught in promise error now even though I followed your codes... I am unsure about where in the codes I should change so that it will work

Comment: FeedbackStats.html:48 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: reponse is not defined this is the error I got. for the response in the foreach part of the loop

Comment: Is it reponse or response ? See if s is missed in the response variable..

Comment: response. I changed it already but still the same error, I think its because of what you said the then() function which deals with a promise so how do i work around this? Is there a way I can send you my full codes as of now?

Comment: Not sure..if you can reproduce the issue in jsfiddle..it will be simple..

Comment: Because my data in the array is from an online database called cloud firestore. I have tweaked my codes and now it does not have that error anymore. But the code you gave as a loop does not work for me.